# Setting an instance equal to a constant?

Tags: swift

The question says "Create a new instance of Spaceship called sameShip and set it equal to falcon."
I know how to create an instance of Spaceship called sameShip but how do I set it equal to falcon? falcon is a constant assigned to an instance of Spaceship btw.

Comment: Lack of relevant tags...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that understand your question well. Did you try the following:

`let sameShip: Spaceship = falcon`